# OpenCV 2.4.6 shows a strange error message in Code::Blocks SVN

Tags: c++, svn, opencv, codeblocks

I configured opencv with codeblocks 12.11 svn (MingW gcc compiler), when I run a code from sample directory of opencv it shows an strange error message related with dlls. Although there have all of dlls. The message says "The procedure entry point *ZNSt8*_detail15_List_node_base11_M_transferEPS0_S1_could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll." and the heading is "Entry Point Error Found". I'm using windows 7 x86. Please help.
How to configure opencv 2.4.6 properly and why this error message shows.

Comment: What IDE are you using: MS Visual Studio, Eclipse or something completely different?

Comment: Have a look through this and reflect on whether you've done everything when setting up the libraries correctly: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to

Comment: CodeBlocks svn (MingW g++ compiler) @Aleksander Lidtke

Comment: Thanks ...Here is given about Visual Studio but I use CodeBlocks (MingW g++ compiler) @Aleksander Lidtke

Comment: No, this doc didn't help. Because these two are different.